# Dealing with the overflow of a 9bit result to an ADD op that is supposed to store in a byte ptr in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

I am working on a problem for my introductory computer organization course at UCI and we use x86 assembly language in the course (using Visual Studio and the MS syntax). While the problem is for a homework assignment, we are graded on attempts and not the correctness of our answers.

My question is w.r.t indirect memory addressing. The entire question is stated below:

> Suppose EBX = 1000 (in decimal) and the byte values stored in the memory addresses 1000 through 1003 are 255, 255, 255, and 255 (in decimal). What effect do the following instructions have (independently) on this area of memory? Assume for multi-byte data, least significant byte is stored in smallest address.
>
> a. ADD byte ptr [EBX], 1
>
> ```
>    ADDRESS | Before | After
>      1000  |  255   |          ; The After column is where we place our answers.
>      1001  |  255   |          ; All of these values are unsigned
>      1002  |  255   |
>      1003  |  255   |
> ```
>
> b. ADD word ptr [EBX], 1
>
> ```
>    ADDRESS | Before | After
>      1000  |  255   |   
>      1001  |  255   |    
>      1002  |  255   |
>      1003  |  255   |
> ```
>
> c. ADD dword ptr [EBX], 1
>
> ```
>    ADDRESS | Before | After
>      1000  |  255   |   
>      1001  |  255   |    
>      1002  |  255   |
>      1003  |  255   |
> ```

I understand that `byte ptr [EBX]` will load the value `0xFF` and that question (A) essentially boils down to `ADD 0xFF, 0x01` using a memory address of one byte. However, what I do not understand is how to deal with the overflow caused by '0x100' which would require a minimum of 9 bits to represent.

The two possible solutions I can determine for question (A) `ADD byte ptr [EBX], 1` are as follows:

> ```
>    ADDRESS | Before | After
>      1000  |  255   |  000    ; Overflow does not carry out to address 1001 and the most significant bit is lost
>      1001  |  255   |  255
>      1002  |  255   |  255
>      1003  |  255   |  255
>
>    ADDRESS | Before | After
>      1000  |  255   |  000    ; Overflow overwrites the value in the next memory address
>      1001  |  255   |  001    ; [base 10]
>      1002  |  255   |  255
>      1003  |  255   |  255
> ```

**QUESTION: what effect does the overflow of representing a 9 bit result of an ADD operation in a single byte of memory have on any subsequent memory regions, if any**

Any insight that anyone could shed on this topic would be greatly appreciated as I was not able to find any x86 specific information that dealt with the overflow of storing a 9 bit number in a single byte of memory.

Comment: Overflow does not carry to the next byte. The operand size matters - if you say `byte`, it's only going to affect that byte. You can of course just check it using a debugger. The extra bit goes into the carry flag (`CF`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I will consult the debugger output next time, although I wasn't sure how I should declare the single byte value. I was just passing in `C/C++ int/short` values into a function I wrapper I wrote, which obviously did not have the same issues regarding the carry on a single byte value.

Comment: Use the adc instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each case, the value retrieved from memory (be it byte, word or doubleword) +1 will yield zero and set the overflow flag because the actual result can't be stored in the space available. That zero will be returned to memory and the CPU will have the overflow bit set in its status register. The fact that the overflow bit is set will allow actions to be executed as a result - it does not affect what is stored to memory.

Think hundreds-tens-units (if that's still taught). If you have 9 and add 1, you get 0 with an "overflow". 99+1 gets 00 +overflow; 999+1 gets 000 +overflow

Comment: But be careful, x86 also has an overflow flag and that is for signed operations, and it will not be set in these cases as in signed these are just `-1+1=0` without overflow.